# Use mockery to unit test a class with dependencies

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, laravel, mockery

I'm new to testing and I am trying to create a unit test that covers the first if statement in the NewsCreator create method.

This question has two parts.

First: How should I be instantiating NewsCreator to handle the mocked validator and repository?

Second: What would the correct way to test this path be?

Here is my controller method that calls the class that needs testing:

```php
public function store()
{
    $creator = new NewsCreator($this);
    return $creator->create(Input::all());
}
```

Here is the class that I wish to test, NewsCreator:

```php
<?php namespace WHS\Portal\News;

class NewsCreator {

    protected $listener;
    protected $repository;
    protected $validator;
    protected $errors;

    public function __construct($listener, NewsRepositoryInterface $repository, NewsValidator $validator)
    {
        $this->listener = $listener;
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->validator = $validator;
        $this->errors = [];
    }
    public function create($data)
    {
        if($this->validator->fails($data))
        {
            return $this->listener->newsCreationFails($this->validator->messages());
        }
        if($this->repository->create($data))
        {
            return $this->listener->newsCreationSucceeds();
        }
        return $this->listener->newsCreationFails($this->errors);
    }
}
```

This is the test I attempted to write, but it fails
with exception:

`2) WHS\Portal\Tests\News\NewsCreatorTest::test_failed_validation Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method fails("foo") from Mockery_1_WHS_Portal_News_NewsValidator should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.`

```php
<?php namespace WHS\Portal\Tests\News;

    use TestCase;
    use Mockery as m;

    class NewsCreatorTest extends TestCase {

        public function tearDown()
        {
            m::close();
        }

        public function test_failed_validation()
        {
            $newsRepo = m::mock('\WHS\Portal\News\DbNewsRepository["create"]');
            $newsValidator = m::mock('\WHS\Portal\News\NewsValidator["fails"]');

            $listener = new NewsListenerStub();
            $listener = m::mock($listener)->makePartial();

            $newsValidator->shouldReceive('fails')->with('foo')->once()->andReturn(true);
            $listener->shouldReceive('newsCreationFails')->once()->with('foo')->andReturn();

            $newsCreator = new \WHS\Portal\News\NewsCreator($listener,$newsRepo,$newsValidator);
            $newsCreator->create([]);
        }
    }
```

Updated test:

```
use TestCase;
use Mockery as m;

class NewsCreatorTest extends TestCase {

    public function tearDown()
    {
        m::close();
    }

    public function test_failed_validation()
    {
        $newsRepo = m::mock('\WHS\Portal\News\DbNewsRepository["create"]');
        $newsValidator = m::mock('\WHS\Portal\News\NewsValidator["fails"]');

        $listener = m::mock('\WHS\Portal\Tests\News\NewsListenerStub["newsCreationFails"]');

        $newsValidator->shouldReceive('fails')->with([])->once()->andReturn(true);
        $newsValidator->shouldReceive('messages')->once();
        $listener->shouldReceive('newsCreationFails')->once()->with('foo')->andReturn('foo-bar');

        $newsCreator = new \WHS\Portal\News\NewsCreator($listener,$newsRepo,$newsValidator);

        $result = $newsCreator->create([]);
        $this->assertEquals('foo-bar', $result);
    }
}
```

The stub class:

```
class NewsListenerStub
{
    public function newsCreationFails($data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `fails()` is called with the `$data` argument in your class.
In your unit test your are passing in an empty array as data `create([])`.
Your argument expectation on the validatorMock is expecting `fails()` to be called with the parameter `foo`. You have to alter that to match the empty array.

```
$newsValidator->shouldReceive('fails')->with([])->once()->andReturn(true);
```

Also you have to specify the `validator->messages()` method on the validatorMock because that is also being called in your class.

```
$newsValidator->shouldReceive('messages')->once();
```

For this test to really make sence you have to assert that the result of `NewsCreationFails` matches the return value of `create()`.

```
$listener->shouldReceive('newsCreationFails')->once()->with('foo')->andReturn('foo-bar');
...
$result = $newsCreator->create([]);

$this->assertEquals('foo-bar', $result);
```

Comment: looks like this is what i nedd, and all seems to go well, except i dont think my listener is being mocked properly.
`1) WHS\Portal\Tests\News\NewsCreatorTest::test_failed_validation
Array () does not match expected type "string".`


i can remove the error by altering the return value in my stub to a string. is that what i should be doing? currently the stub method newsCreationFailed($data) just returns $data

Comment: You can mock your listener similar to your other mocks. Why did you create a seperate stub class?

Comment: as any class can be the listener, i wasn't sure on what to do. i figured just create a dummy class with only the required method newsCreationFails. ive added the test as it currently stands, as well as the stub class

Comment: I assume all the listeners implement a common interface. If not, you really should. You can typehint the interface in your constructor and easily mock the interface.

Comment: Btw, you can simplify your mock definition `m::mock('\WHS\Portal\News\DbNewsRepository["create"]');` to `m::mock('\WHS\Portal\News\DbNewsRepository');`. The last parameter is only needed if you want to create a partial mock (proxying not defined methods) or if the class you are mocking doesn't exists.

Comment: i changed my listener and validator to implement interfaces, and made a few minor changes to the test  to reflect that like m::mock('NewsRepositoryInterface'), and we have a passing test. Really appreciate your help

Comment: Nice, glad you got it working! It is good practice to depend on abstractions (interfaces, abstract classes) instead of concretions as it allows you to easily switch implementations without needing to alter the consuming class (NewsCreator) or the unit tests. This is also called "Liskov substitution principle".